# how to get records of previous day using tsql?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I need all the records from last day?

Hi

```
Select * from table1 where tabledate > getdate() -1
```

with this query, i need to run is exactly after midnight to get exact result. I need to run it  in day time and get all the previous day's records.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL statement to select all rows from previous day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503298/sql-statement-to-select-all-rows-from-previous-day)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In SQL Server 2005, this is generally the fastest way to convert a datetime to a date:

```
DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, yourDate), 0)
```

In your case, it's done only once, so the how doesn't really matter much.  But it does give the following query.

```
Select
  *
from
  table1
where
      tabledate >= DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, getDate()) - 1, 0)
  AND tabledate <  DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, getDate()),     0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this page out. It is a great resource for calculating dates.

http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/robyn-pages-sql-server-datetime-workbench/#calculatingdates

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to use `DATEDIFF` alone:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, tabledate, GETDATE()) = 1
```

A datediff of 1 for day covers any time in the previous day.

Comment: And it will also bludgeon the optimiser with a huge rock.  If the `tabledate` field is indexed, this version will *not* be able to use a range seek on the index.  Instead it will need to ***scan*** the whole index calculating the DATEDIFF() on every unique value.  This is because the field being searched is now hidden inside your function call.  The alternative is slightly longer, but keeps all the function calls on constants, and so allows the much faster ***seek***.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @d SMALLDATETIME;
SET @d = DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE());

SELECT <cols> FROM dbo.table1
  WHERE tabledate >= DATEADD(DAY, -1, d)
  AND tabledate < @d;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
your_field = cast(dateadd(D,-1,getdate()) as DATE)
```