# Get data changed 2 hours back in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I changed data for record with id 12 in column **_column** in table **_table** two hours back. But now I want it back. Followed [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503298/sql-statement-to-select-all-rows-from-previous-day) but not getting what is said. Can someone help me to retrieve it back.

Comment: Do you not have any backups of the DB you could restore to another DB and query?

Comment: This will be the final option for me. If there is somehow I can get that data without updating, please tell. If there is no way, please tell how to rollback to previous value.

Comment: @bendataclear : No backups :(

Comment: What is your recovery model for the DB (eg Simple, Full)?

Comment: What you mean by `changed` ? was it an update operation?

Comment: @Kaf : I right clicked the table and opened Edit 200 records. Table opened and I changed the value from there.

Comment: What are the values `before` and `after` changing? and the column names of your table?

Comment: @Kaf : No offense but how does that matter ? Also,I have written the column and table name in question. It is _column and _table

Comment: It does matter to build a query to revert back to your original state.

Comment: Ok. Consider the old value as _oldValue and new value as _newValue

Comment: Then make your new value to old value ;). I wasn't trying to nick your data.

Comment: @Kaf : I am sure you were not :) But I can't write it. I hope you understand.

Comment: Have you tried the restore mathed answered by @Thato?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your database is in FULL or Bulk-Logged recovery model and that you are at least doing transaction log backups. You would need to restore transaction log backups by using the STOPAT option.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321836

[HOW TO RESTORE TO A POINT IN TIME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179451%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

> ```
> RESTORE DATABASE AdventureWorks FROM DISK = 'C:\AdventureWorks.BAK' 
> WITH NORECOVERY
> GO 
> RESTORE LOG AdventureWorks FROM DISK = 'C:\AdventureWorks.TRN' 
> WITH RECOVERY, 
> STOPAT = 'Feb 05, 2013 05:31:00 PM' 
> GO
> ```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

That question you linked is related to actually returning rows minus a day, not data recovery.
Are you trying to recover data that has actually been changed 2 hours ago? If so, I do not believe it's possible unless you were to attempt some sort of HD recovery process which can get quite messy.