# Year/Month/Week to date SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am currently developing a platform where I need 3 SQL queries to return all records between Year/Month/Week to date.

The queries have to work dynamically without hard-coded dates, please bear with me if i should split these up into 3 questions, i think they are very relatable and that's why i put all 3 in here :)

**1: Year To Date**

I tried this SQL query according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18925557/datediff-parameter-issue) question about Year To Date but I am receiving an error:

Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF'

```
SELECT coins_daily_date, coins_daily_high, coins_daily_low, coins_daily_close, coins_daily_volume
FROM coins_daily
WHERE coins_daily_date BETWEEN DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,GETDATE()), 0) AND GETDATE()
ORDER BY coins_daily_date ASC
```

**2: Month To Date**

I tried different things with the month function but could not figure out how to achieve/build a correct month to date SQL query.

**3: Week To Date**

Honestly, I have no idea where, to begin with, this one.

**Works fine going back 1 year**

```
SELECT coins_daily_date, coins_daily_high, coins_daily_low, coins_daily_close, coins_daily_volume
FROM coins_daily
WHERE coins_daily_date >= DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -1 YEAR
ORDER BY coins_daily_date ASC
```

I hope someone can help or point me in the right direction :)

Best regards!

Comment: Your DATEDIFF has three params. It only should have 2. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GETDATE() is for MsSQL.  Use NOW() for current datetime or curdate() for current date.

For year-to-date :

```
SELECT coins_daily_date, coins_daily_high, coins_daily_low, coins_daily_close, 
coins_daily_volume
FROM coins_daily
WHERE YEAR(coins_daily_date) = YEAR(NOW())
AND coins_daily_date <= NOW()
ORDER BY coins_daily_date ASC
```

For month-to-date :

```
SELECT coins_daily_date, coins_daily_high, coins_daily_low, coins_daily_close, 
coins_daily_volume
FROM coins_daily
WHERE YEAR(coins_daily_date) = YEAR(NOW())
AND MONTH(coins_daily_date) = MONTH(NOW())
AND coins_daily_date <= NOW()
ORDER BY coins_daily_date ASC
```

For week-to-date :

```
SELECT coins_daily_date, coins_daily_high, coins_daily_low, coins_daily_close, 
coins_daily_volume
FROM coins_daily
WHERE YEAR(coins_daily_date) = YEAR(NOW())
AND WEEK(coins_daily_date) = WEEK(NOW())
AND coins_daily_date <= NOW()
ORDER BY coins_daily_date ASC
```

Comment: Your Year To Date works perfectly, i do however get this error on the month to date qyery: 'MONTH(coins_daily_date) = MONTH(NOW()) AND coins_daily_date <= NOW() ORDER BY

And this one in the Week To Date 'WEEK(coins_daily_date) = WEEK(NOW()) AND coins_daily_date <= NOW() ORDER BY coin'

Comment: @Daniel, you're missing an `AND` after your first condition for the MTD and WTD queries.

Comment: Sorry, I were too fast ;-)