# Perl: how to know if 24hrs have passed?

Tags: perl, date, time, elapsed

I have a timestamp field on a mysql table , i want to know if that timestamp is 24hrs old or more. What would be the best way to do that in Perl?

Comment: It would all depend on the database load, whether you use the tools on the DB or in the perl process.  There are some good answers below for each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By timestamp I am assuming it's Unix timestamp, i.e. seconds since epoch.

```
my $ts       = 1393662619;
my $day_24hr = 24 * 60 * 60;    ## seconds in 24 hrs

my $prev_time = time() - $day_24hr;    ## 24hours ago

if ( $ts < $prev_time ) {
    print "timestamp is 24 hour old";
}
```

Comment: Seems a good approach but i don't get your $ts? it is a mysql data type "timestamp', the format is(i.e.) 1970-01-31 00:00:00

Comment: it worked as desired, but i had to add code to convert mysql timestap to unix timestamp

Answer (score 3):

SQL that would return the timestamp 24 hours ago.

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
```

Now if your timestamp is < the timestamp returned by the above SQL , 24 hours have passed.

Answer (score 2):

The best thing is to let the database do the work. See [SQL statement to select all rows from previous day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503298/sql-statement-to-select-all-rows-from-previous-day) for an example.

Comment: This would be a better response if you just added some simple SQL as an example

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`localtime`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/localtime.html) for that.

```
($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) = localtime($unix_timestamp);
```

Comment: And then you build the timestamp yourself?