# Selecting Yesterdays Records using DateTime Field

Tags: sql, datetime, ms-access, select

I'm trying to select from a table all of yesterdays records (not the last 24 hours worth of records). The field in question is defined as `DateTime` (in Access 2007) and is formatted `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss`.

My first thoughts (as per many other [Q&A's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503298/sql-statement-to-select-all-rows-from-previous-day)) would be to take an approach like:

```
SELECT * FROM someTable WHERE DateAdded = DateAdd("d", -1, Now())
```

As mentioned though, the fields format means that no results are returned as the condition compares the time value as well.

My next thought was to convert the `DateTime` fields into dates like so:

```
SELECT * FROM someTable WHERE cDate(Added) = DateAdd("d", -1, cDate(Now()))
```

Once again, no records are returned though.

If I run the following queries though, both return `29/10/2014`:

```
--SELECT yesterdays date
SELECT DateAdd("d", -1, cDate(Now())) --Returns 29/10/2014

--SELECT the date of the last record
SELECT TOP 1 cDate(Added) FROM someTable ORDER BY Added DESC --Returns 29/10/2014
```

So my question is how do you select yesterdays records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your WHERE clause needs to include all Date/Time values from yesterday (i.e. the 24-hour period between yesterday at midnight and today at midnight), so you need to do

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM someTable
WHERE DateAdded >= DateAdd("d", -1, Date())
    AND DateAdded < Date()
```