# Extracting data from MSSQL using PHP in a desired format

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a MS Sql table already made. Each row has a column called RECORD_DATE which consists of the current date. How should I query to always extract the previous days(yesterdays date) row data on the current day? Also this table is dynamic, it keeps inserting and updating a new row(s) everyday but the date is unique to a particular row.

Comment: Here is the example [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503298/sql-statement-to-select-all-rows-from-previous-day)

Answer (score -1):

Use mysql Function like this

```
SELECT * FROM tb WHERE DATEDIFF(now(),dt) = 1
```

Comment: the question is tagged sql-server