# Recover data only from the previous day in a table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to retrieve data from a table that has date referenced only the previous day, I am trying to do with the query below but I am not getting:

```
SELECT 
    Log.ValorEntrada, Log.DataHoraEvento, Log.NumeroEntrada 
FROM 
    Log 
WHERE 
    Log.DataHoraEvento = (GETDATE()-1)
```

How can I get this result?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL statement to select all rows from previous day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503298/sql-statement-to-select-all-rows-from-previous-day)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL Server, `GETDATE()` has a time component.  I would recommend:

```
WHERE Log.DataHoraEvento >= CAST(GETDATE()-1 as DATE) AND
      Log.DataHoraEvento < CAST(GETDATE() as DATE)
```

This condition is "sargable", meaning that an index can be used.  The following also is:

```
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, Log.DataHoraEvento) >= CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
```

Almost all functions prevent the use of indexes, but conversion/casting to a date is an exception.

Finally, if you don't care about indexes, you can also write this as:

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(day, Log.DataHoraEvento, GETDATE()) = 1
```

`DATEDIFF()` with `day` as the first argument counts the number of "day" boundaries between the two date/times.  Everything that happened yesterday has exactly one date boundary.

Answer (score 1):

If `DataHoraEvento` is a `DATETIME`, its likely that it has the full time, hence `GETDATE()-1` isn't getting any matches. You should search for a range like this:

```
SELECT L.ValorEntrada, L.DataHoraEvento, L.NumeroEntrada 
FROM dbo.[Log] L
WHERE L.DataHoraEvento >= CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(DAY,-1,GETDATE()))
AND L.DataHoraEvento < CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Log.ValorEntrada, Log.DataHoraEvento, Log.NumeroEntrada 
FROM   Log 
WHERE  Log.DataHoraEvento >= DATEADD(dd,DATEDIFF(dd,1,GETDATE()),0) 
AND    Log.DataHoraEvento < DATEADD(dd,DATEDIFF(dd,0,GETDATE()),0)
```

You should also use [SYSDATETIME()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sysdatetime-transact-sql) (if you on SQL Server 2008+) instead of GETDATE() as this gives you datetime2(7) precision.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
MEMBER BETWEEN DATEADD(day, -2, GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())
```