# SQL Select Records based on current date minus two days

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, getdate, sql-date-functions

I have an orders table which contains an order ID, order date and order description.

I want to run a select query which captures all orders that have been created in the last two days. so the current date minus two days. from the 14th December, I would want to select all orders where the order date is > 13th December. This needs to use a Get date function to pick up the current date and minus the days.

I have tried:

```
select * from orders where orderdate > getdate() - 2
```

but this is not producing the correct results. Any idea's how to do this please?

Comment: use convert( varchar(10), orderdate,120) =  convert( varchar(10), getdate()-2,120)  in where clause

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL statement to select all rows from previous day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503298/sql-statement-to-select-all-rows-from-previous-day)

Comment: You contradict yourself:  "created prior to the last two days" vs "from the 14th December, I would want to select all orders where the order date is > 13th December".   If the date is GREATER than 13th, that's NOT "prior to".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you should try to use [`dateadd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql) function

```
select * from orders where orderdate > dateadd(dd,-1,cast(getdate() as date))
```

Now, this may be exactly what you need but then you need to understand that by casting to date we remove the time part and effectively go back to the start of the day and a day behind it(-1) gives the start of yesterday.

Comment: That has worked, thank you and thank you for the explanation, this will help in the future!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
select * from orders where orderdate > cast(getdate() - 1 as date)
```

Comment: For years I used dateadd(day .. , for no reason. Thank you!

`select * from orders where orderdate > getdate() - 1` 
works as well, without the cast!!

Answer (score 3):

If you want the orders of the last two days, use `DATEADD` to add days to today's date (in your case -2 days) then use `DATEDIFF` to compare the two days:

```
SELECT * FROM orders
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, DATEADD(DAY, -2, GETDATE()), orderdate) > 0
```

Now, assuming all orders have dates in the past and none in the future (which is what it should be), you can simply use `DATEDIFF` like this:

```
SELECT * FROM orders
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, orderdate, GETDATE()) <= 2
```

Note: you can use `< 3` instead of `<= 2`.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like dateadd and convert will solve the problem.

```
select   o.*
from     orders o
where    o.orderdate >= dateadd(day, -2, convert(date, getdate()))
```