# I want to display matches in next 48hrs in sql..I am having column as matchdate.Can someone help me out with it.?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select * from matchdate
where (matchdate) = DATEADD(DAY, +2, getdate())
```

Comment: Please tell how it is different than https://stackoverflow.com/q/47818266/4636715

Answer (score 0):

You want an inequality:

```
where matchdate >= convert(date, getdate()) and
      matchdate < convert(date, DATEADD(DAY, +2, getdate()))
```

This assumes that you want calendar days.  If you want 48 hours:

```
where matchdate >= getdate() and
      matchdate < DATEADD(hour, 48, getdate())
```

Answer (score 0):

1st You should not call table with same column name in it, next time try something with T_matchdate as table.
2nd not equal but greater

```
select * 
from (select * from matchdate)T_matchdate 
where matchdate > DATEADD(DAY, +2, getdate()) 
and matchdate <= GetDate()
```

You can try to find date by more SQLish way

```
select * 
from (select * from matchdate) T_matchdate 
where (matchdate) > sysdate 
and  matchdate < sysdate+2
```