# Selecting all rows that are between yesterday's date time and todays date and time

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to selected all columns upon a certain condition. That condition is that the datetimes must be between yesterday at 5:30pm and today at 6pm. My only question is how to I get the 5:30pm? I understood how to get 5pm but how would I add the minutes.

Here is the query that I am using based off of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503298/sql-statement-to-select-all-rows-from-previous-day)

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl 
WHERE datelog BETWEEN dateadd(hour,17,datediff(day,1,GETDATE())) 
                  AND dateadd(hour,18,datediff(day,0,GETDATE()))
```

Comment: This will answer your question. - https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/110730/query-to-get-yesterdays-data-only-for-a-specific-time-interval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current `dateadd` will return yesterday at 5:00 PM. Simply add 30 minutes to that `dateadd` using another `dateadd`. It will look like: `dateadd(minute, 30, [your current dateadd])`

Using your code:

```
dateadd(MINUTE, 30, dateadd(hour, 17, datediff(day, 1, GETDATE())))
```

Comment: That was perfect! So chaining the functions is what I needed

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server, I would expect:

```
where datelog >= dateadd(minute, 17*60+30, dateadd(hour, -24, convert(date, getdate()))) and
      datelog < dateadd(minute, 18*60, convert(date, getdate()))
```

`datediff()` does not make sense in this construct.