# Find rows that have yesterdays date -- Invalid column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, casting, dateadd

**Goal**: I am trying to get the rows in a table that have yesterdays date (but the original column is in datetime).

**What I've tried**:
I was able to figure out how to get yesterdays date from  https://learnsql.com/cookbook/how-to-get-yesterdays-date-in-t-sql/

But I also had to cast the DateTime from the table to date to match that yesterdays date was in Date format. So the SO articles like [SQL statement to select all rows from previous day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503298/sql-statement-to-select-all-rows-from-previous-day) did not work.

When I try to find the matching rows from my DB Table, it says:

> Invalid column name 'YesterdayDate'

**SQL**:

```
SELECT cast(DateEnded as date) AS YesterdayDate
FROM [dbo].[V]
WHERE YesterdayDate = DATEADD(DAY, -1, CAST(GETDATE() AS date));
```

How can I correctly do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact don't do it that way. You want to avoid calling functions on columns in your `WHERE` clause as they can make the query unsargable i.e. unable to use indexes. Instead use the actual column, and rather than converting to a date use a datetime window of the previous day.

```
SELECT CAST(DateEnded AS date) AS YesterdayDate
FROM [dbo].[V]
WHERE DateEnded >= DATEADD(DAY, -1, CAST(GETDATE() AS date))
AND DateEnded < CAST(GETDATE() AS date);
```

Comment: @s.soltanzadeh please do not make edits which fundamentally change an answer. Add your own if you think its suitable.