# How can i do an order by in a select only if a column is a certain value?

Tags: sql

I have a table , MyTable. I want to select all rows that are a day less than the current date.  So if today is the 23 , i want to select everything that is for the 22. But i want to do a count(*) and the column is createddate.

I have tried this :

```
select count(*) from MyTable where createddate = getdate() -1 order by createddate desc
```

Is this the right syntax , how can i do this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL statement to select all rows from previous day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503298/sql-statement-to-select-all-rows-from-previous-day)

Comment: Since you're trying to use `getdate()` I assume that you're using SQL Server, and the linked question should be appropriate. Please tag with the exact DBMS you're using. They're all different.

Comment: What is the datatype of `createddate`?

Comment: Add a tag for the dbms used. (`getdate()` is a non-standard function.)

Answer (score 0):

`getdate()` returns the current time and date, so you need to remove the current time (so you get "today's date"), then deduct 1 day (so you get "yesterday"). Using `cast(getdate() as date)` removes the current time and `dateadd(day,-1, ... )` deducts one day.

As you don't specify the data type of `createddate` it may also carry time of day (e.g. if datetime or datetime2) so for a reliable method of finding all rows for yesterday, **for any date related data type**, use a "date range" like this:

```
select count(*) as count_rows
from mytable
where createddate >= dateadd(day,-1,cast(getdate() as date)) -- greater than or equal to "yesterday"
and createddate < cast(getdate() as date) -- less than "today"
```

Now, if you only want the count of records, there can only be one row returned, and hence there is no need to use an order by clause at all.